# come to one's own

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Dictionaries say if someone or something **comes into their own**, they become very successful or start to perform very well because the circumstances are right.

But I have a sentence in which the phrase obviously means something else, and I couldn't find it in any dictionary.

From [Song of Myself, by Walt Whitman](https://poets.org/poem/song-myself-20):

> ```
> I exist as I am, that is enough. 
> If no other in the world be aware I sit content. 
> And if each and all be aware I sit content. 
> One world is aware and by far the largest to me, 
>    and that is myself. 
> And whether **I come to my own to-day** or in ten
>    thousand or ten million years,
> I can cheerfully take it now, or with equal 
>    cheerfulness I can wait.
> ```

Here, I think, the phrase means "to die". But is it possible "come to one's own" signifies such a meaning?

Comment: As a single sentence, it's meaningless—or at least open to interpretation. The intended meaning can only be known for sure with more context.

Comment: I exist as I am, that is enough.
If no other in the world be aware I sit content.
And if each and all be aware I sit content.

One world is aware and by far the largest to me, and that is myself.
And whether I come to my own to-day or in ten thousand or ten million years,
I can cheerfully take it now, or with equal cheerfulness I can wait.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about the interpretation of poetry.

Comment: @Xanne I'll refrain from voting due to conflict of interest but the question actually isn't what the poem means but does "come to one's own" have a different meaning from "come into one's own" or, if they are identical, is there an alternate meaning. I have the same dim sense as the OP that there is a meaning connected with death, but the poem doesn't seem to come into it. Where that leaves this post is beyond me, vis a vis the forum rules.

Comment: @GetzelR That’s the problem with poetry. Whitman is so well-known that one can probably find analyses of this on-line, but then so can the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I exist as I am, that is enough. --> *I am self content/self satisfied.*

If no other in the world be aware I sit content. --> *I am self content/self satisfied; what others think matters not, even if **no one** is aware.*

And if each and all be aware I sit content. --> *I am self content/self satisfied; what other think matters not, even if **everyone** is aware.*

One world is aware and by far the largest to me, 
   and that is myself. --> *All that matters is that **I** am content/satisfied **with myself**.*

And whether **I come to my own to-day** or in ten
   thousand or ten million years,
I can cheerfully take it now, or with equal 
   cheerfulness I can wait. -- ***I come to my own one day*** means **to die**. I am so content/satisfied with myself that I would cheerfully die now or cheerfully die later. It doesn't matter. All that matters is that **I** am content/satisfied **with myself**.

**To come to my own to-day** has nothing to do with *to come into one's own*. The author has made it abundantly clear he's already done that. In context, **to come to my own to-day** means **to come to my own *end* to-day**, *to die today*.

Comment: I read it the same way at first, perhaps under the influence of the OP and my own vague recollection, but I tried and failed to find one other example of this usage. That's not to say it isn't legitimate, but I'd love to see another example.

Answer (score 1):

In that poem it is preceded by the lines

> If no other in the world be aware I sit content,
>
> And if each and all
>   be aware I sit content.
>
> One world is aware and by far the largest to me, and that is myself,

He is dismissing recognition as unimportant. It seems plausible that by "come to my own" he means "come into my own" - to be recognized as successful.

(Then again, I am almost certain I've read "come to my own" in other contexts to mean death and it fits the poem too, but I can't seem to find anything like that...)

edit: <strike>Thinking it over, I'm certain that the meaning here is recognition, not death. This piece is as far from nihilistic as it gets and saying I can cheerfully die now or in a million years doesn't quite fit. (That, and he calls himself "deathless")</strike>

edit 2: On third thought. Poetry...

I should delete my answer but I'll leave it just for the record. Death seems to be a possible (probable?) meaning: "I am deathless [...] I shall not pass [...] my foothold is tenon'd and mortis'd in granite (strong) I laugh at what you call dissolution." See @RichardKayer answer.

Comment: So what does that mean? Does it mean "recognize myself"?

Comment: "Come (in)to ones own" means success and recognition and the question is being raised is it also used to mean death, which is inconclusive/unsupported. The poem's meaning (as noted, not really the purpose of this forum) seems to be: I don't care if I'm recognized by others now or in millions of years, because I recognize myself/my own worth.